# Flutter pass value of counter to another page

Tags: android, flutter, counter, pass-data

Hello guys i want to pass the data of a counter to a new screen in flutter. I already tried to put the data in the constructor but it wont work. This is the code:

```
  int _counterb = 0;
```

```
setState(() {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder:
            (BuildContext context) =>
              Draw(_counterb: _counterb),
            ),
        );
      });
```

So how can I pass this data of _counterb to the second page?

EDIT

I solved the problem. But now I run into another one. I want to pass 12 values. But it only takes two. How can I pass more than 2 positional arguments?

Comment: You can pass any number of arguments in the constructor. Just declare them in your Draw class

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing your `_counterb` variable on the `Draw` page?

I am assuming Draw is `StatefulWidget`

```
class Draw extends StatefulWidget {
  final int counter1, counter2, counter3; //Declare any number of variables you want
  const Draw({this.counter1, this.counter2, this.counter3});

  @override
  DrawState createState() => DrawState();
}

class DrawState extends State<Draw> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("${widget.counter1} ${widget.counter2} ${widget.counter3}");
  }
}
```

Your `Navigator` will look like this

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder:
            (BuildContext context) =>
              Draw(counter1: _counter1, counter2: _counter2, counter3: _counter3),
            ),
        );
```

Comment: Yes i tried it and it worked copletely fine.

Comment: The only problem is that i want to pass more than one value...

Comment: When i add a third value, then it says "Too many positional argument: 2 expected, but 3 found"

Comment: Okay understood that means in the Draw class you have declared only two variables. So you need to declare your third variable in the Draw class to pass it in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using provider or getx to manage the state in the app instead of passing 12 arguments to different screens;

if you still want to do so, you can send the data to the second screen through `settings`

for example:

```
   Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder:
            (BuildContext context) =>
              Draw(),
              settings: RouteSettings(arguments: {'counterb': _counterb,},),
            ),
        );
```

and accessing it in the Draw() screen through:

```
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final routeArg =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
    final counterb = routeArg['counterb'];
}
```

also setState() is not needed here